# Find all Base R function names that contain the word `list`

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there might be a way to find all Base R function names that contain the string `"list"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lsf.str` returns all the functions in a particular package, you can then use `grep` with the keyword and return all the names of the functions which match it.

```
grep("list", lsf.str("package:base"), value = TRUE)

# [1] "[.Dlist"                 "[.listof"                "[.simple.list"          
# [4] "alist"                   "all.equal.list"          "as.data.frame.list"     
# [7] "as.list"                 "as.list.data.frame"      "as.list.Date"           
#[10] "as.list.default"         "as.list.environment"     "as.list.factor"         
#[13] "as.list.function"        "as.list.numeric_version" "as.list.POSIXct"        
#[16] "as.list.POSIXlt"         "as.pairlist"             "iconvlist"              
#[19] "is.list"                 "is.pairlist"             "list"                   
#[22] "list.dirs"               "list.files"              "list2env"               
#[25] "pairlist"                "print.Dlist"             "print.listof"           
#[28] "print.simple.list"       "sort.list"               "unlist"                 
#[31] "within.list"
```

Answer (score 4):

`objects` is the sibling function of `ls` (List Objects).

```
objects("package:base", pattern ="list")
```

Use `apropos` and `find` for finding objects in the whole search path.